# Ways to the loop through all fields in mongoengine Document and check if each field is particular type and is_required

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Here is some field in a Document using mongoengine

```
_id     = f.ObjectIdField(db_field="i", required=True)
name    = f.StringField(db_field="n")
```

I would like to loop through each field in the Document and see if they are type XField and is_required is True, is there a way of doing that?

I know you can list out all fields using `_fields`

but

```
for field in SomeDocument._fields:
    print type(field) # always return 'str' not 'StringField' or 'ObjectField'

    # Don't know how to check is_required
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use this

```
field_dict = SomeDocument.get_fields_info()
for field_name, field in field_dict.iteritems():
    print field_name, field.required, field.__class__
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue you were having is that `SomeDocument._fields` is a dictionary, so iterating on it is giving you the keys (which are strings).  For instance if you have a field `foo`, you can do `SomeDocument._fields['foo'].required`.  And of course you can do something like:

```
for field in SomeDocument._fields:
    print '{} {} required.'.format(SomeDocument._fields[field], 'is' if SomeDocument._fields[field].required else 'is not')
```